# Autohotkey - Open folder in Explorer window - problem with special chars in path

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to open folders, with special (Hungarian) chars in paths. The following code is perfectly works with paths without special chars.

```
path:="D:\Ajtó" ;('ó' is just an example, several other special chars could occur)
OutputDebug, % path
Run, Explorer /n`,/e`,%path% , , Max
```

I got back in Output Window the following:

> D:\AjtĂł

This isn't a real folder. I've been trying with 'FileEncoding', but no success.
Does anyone have any idea where could I start to converting/encoding the path?
AHK Version 1.1.33.10 (Unicode)

Comment: Make sure your script is saved with “UTF-8 with BOM” encoding.

Comment: Thank you @user3419297! Yes, that was the problem: I've created the file in VS Code, which saved the file in UTF-8. When I created a new .ahk file in a 'regular' way (right click in windows file explorer, create new .ahk), that was saved in UTF-8 BOM inherently.